# Graph $r =\ln(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

One of the exercises in the Precalculus book I am studying has this polar equation that has to be graphed: $$r = \ln(\theta)$$

I have not yet met with such equations. Of course, it is not technically difficult to compute values of this equation as it is just a natural logarithm, but I am surprised to see it because till now I have seen only trigonometric functions used with any angles' values. Could you, please, advise a link, or any material, or a brief explanation here that describes such usage and its mathematical and logical meaning and applications?

Comment: I would guess that the intention of the author would be to test if you know how to graph the equation.  The equation doesn't necessarily have any meaning or applications.

Comment: I agree with mathematician's comment and would (**speculatively**) go further.  I surmise that part of the point of the assignment is to attack your intuition with the idea that graphing $r = f(\theta)$ can be meaningful even when you don't normally associate $r$ (i.e. the magnitude of $[x + iy]$) with the specific function $f(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the unique angle [within $2\pi$] such that $\cos(\theta) = x/r$ and $\sin(\theta) = y/r$.

Answer (score 1):

*A cartesian inverse function* where variables $(x,y)$ are    swapped we have
$$ f(x,y) \rightarrow f(y,x)$$

The straight line (green) stands between the relations and corresponding graphs (red,blue).
Example
$$y=e^{x},\; x= \log_{e}y \rightarrow y=\log_e x\;$$

[image]

Similarly *a polar inverse function* where variables $(r,\theta)$ are   swapped can also be understood
and visualized. we have with same logic of independent variables:

$$ g(r,\theta) \rightarrow g(\theta,r)$$

An archimedean spiral  (green) stands between the above two  relations/graphs (red,blue).
Example
$$r=e^{\theta},\; \theta= \log_{e}r \rightarrow r=\log_e \theta\;$$

The blue spiral $\log \theta$ can thus be be viewed as taking its logical position as a *polar coordinate inverse of the equiangular spiral* and vice-versa.

The relationship is inverse exponential, not to be confused with reciprocal exponential.

I am not aware of any applications; large number of $\theta$ revolutions can be represented by its smaller logarithm number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot of the polar graph for $r = \ln(\theta)$, where $\theta \geq 0$:

[[image: <span class=]$r = \ln(\theta)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL2K6.gif)

Credits: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that the curve looks like this. I did "draw" it on Desmos calculator before posting my question here. My question was not about how it looks, but about its logical meaning and its applications, as I have never yet seen angles used with logs.

Comment: @Vitale, I searched Google and found no *meaningful results*.  That is, as indicated by [mathematician](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/98943), "the equation $r = \ln(\theta)$ (where $\theta \geq 1$) does not necessarily have any meaning or applications".

Comment: Yes, my bad!  I meant $\theta \geq 0$.  Corrected.  Thanks, @g.kov!  =)

Comment: Very intuitively put, a function takes an element (in most cases a number), then tortures it to become another element (another number). It doesn't care if the number it takes is your mother's age, the number of deaths today in Moscow, the length the Brooklyn Bridge or in this case an "angle". Remember also that an angle (measured in radians) is a number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guessing. I can think of one use of the function is that it shows how a curve can fill up a 2-dimensional region (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ictskuushq). When $\theta$ is sufficiently large, the circles formed by the function are extremely close to each other, i.e. $\ln(\theta+2\pi)-\ln(\theta)=O(1/\theta)$, this could be used in theories of filling up a plane with a curve, something like fibers in differential geometry or computer graphics.

Besides, I feel it actually visualize the ln function better than using x, y. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/27aex4oysb